# How do I test out production confluence cloud plugin?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am able to test out my confluence cloud plugin with the base url set to:

`{{localBaseUrl}}`

This loads the plugin fine on my confluence test environment that's hosted on `my_project.atlassian.net`... 
When I update the `baseUrl` in my `atlassian-connect.json` it's unable to load the same plugin when I run `npm start` and have the plugin files uploaded to the S3 account (It throws this: `Tunnel 0e6e0931.ngrok.io not found`).  it's able to create the marketplace listing though..  How do I test my plugin to make sure it'll work in production?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if I create a `private` listing, I can view the app page, grab the install url and install via UPM.  This will verify if the production app works before going live.

Comment: If this is the answer, then accept it by clicking on the tick to mark the question completed.